# nscd+centos7+curl - 0% DNS cache hit rate :/

Tags: caching, curl, amazon-ec2, dns

So I've been profiling our internal queries and realised we don't have DNS caching enabled. No problems I think, install nscd and follow [this guide](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2011/03/27/configuring-nscd-to-cache-dns-host-lookups/) to get it configured.

Everything is running but I don't get the desired speed up.

Think I've got everything in this paste that's pertinent, http://pastebin.com/ReUWxzKM

I'm running the cURL request from an EC2 instance, to another EC2 instance inside the same VPC. The actual request takes ~5-8ms vs DNS lookup ~150ms.

Running the same cURL command from my macbook gets cached DNS lookup ~3-4ms. Was hoping to get the same speed up server-side!

Any suggestions on how to get cURL to use nscd?

Comment: PS. What I'm looking to achieve, if the NSCD solution isn't viable is to reduce the TTFB to < 5ms. Our internal DNS addresses have mostly got 600s TTLs, ideally would like the caching daemon to respect this, but not a deal breaker if it doesn't, don't mind if it's in the cfg file like the NSCD solution.

Comment: I could not reproduce that on my Centos7 (but I did find nscd statistic either wrong or unintuitive). Have you considered trying dnsmasq instead?

Comment: @DusanBajic no I haven't tried dnsmasq yet, will give that a shot and see if that solves the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `shared hosts yes` enabled, which will bypass cache access statistics since nscd is no longer in the access path. See [this article](https://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2006/02/08/viewing-name-service-cache-statistics/) for an example. It's a common mistake since the nscd.conf man page does not explicitly spell it out.